# Can not use _Layout from areas in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have the following structure:

[image: structure]

I want to use different master page for Admin Areas. Links to Views in Admin _Layout look like "~/Admin/Home/Welcome"

```
<ul>
                    <li><a href="~Admin/Home/Welcome">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="~Admin/Home/Tours">Tours</a>
                    </li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions how to make it work properly?

Comment: @Snesh Could you please look at it?

Comment: "~Admin/Home/Welcome" ... is this a typo? shouldn't it be "~/Admin/Home/Welcome"??

Comment: omg you're right ! stupid mistake... made some changes in code and it's woking now!  @matt_lethargic

Comment: It's super easy to overlook things when you've been looking at them for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "~Admin/Home/Welcome" to "~/Admin/Home/Welcome"